# What is the correct ticker for the S&P 500?

Tags: united-states, standard-and-poors-500

I want to allocate 10% of my income to the S&P 500. Insure stable growth over time. For this purpose, I opened a Robinhood account and looked up S&P.....oh boy there is like gazillion of S&P

```
SPY
IVY
VOO
SPXL
XBI
SDS
SSO
SPGI
SPXU
```

Which one is the true and only S&P 500 that I can start investing 10% of my income? Which one is stable, reliable, consistent?

Answer (score 4):

The S&P 500 is just an index - a list of specific stocks, it is not an investible instrument. What you are finding are some ETFs that *track* the S&P 500's returns, as well as ETFs that track other indices (like the Dow Jones US Index) and other variants or segments of the S&P 500 (e.g. XBI is specific to Biotech).

Of the ones you list, SPY, IVV, and VOO should track the actual S&P 500 index the closest.  They are 3 ETFs created by different companies that are designed to mimic the index.

Answer (score 1):

Only SPY, IVV, and VOO are "true and only".

If you are holding it for years, they are equally "stable, reliable, consistent".

If you sometimes buy/sell at extreme volatility, e.g. Market Order on Open, SPY is more consistent intra-day, at slightly higher expense.